# Non blocking solution to a setTimeout() and Performance thoughts

Tags: javascript, animation, asynchronous, settimeout, nonblocking

I'm performing animation and drawings.
What i'm trying to achieve is the following:

If the current value is greather than the defined peak value the current value is the new peak value.
If there isn't any peak values for 800ms, the last current value will be the peak value anyway.

```
function animate() {
    if (ready){
        setTimeout(function() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(animate);
            draw();
        }, interval);
    }
}

function draw(){
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if ((currentValue[i] > peak[i] ) || timeOutTriggered[i]) {
            peak[i] = currentValue[i];  
            clearTimeout(timer[i]);
            timeOutTriggered[i] = false;
            timer[i] = setTimeout(callback.bind(undefined, i), 800);        
        }
    }
    drawPieces();
}   

function callback(i){    
    timeOutTriggered[i] = true;
}
```

From what i read around this solution is asynchronous in the sense that the counting is performed in the same thread, so from time to time there will be a timer scheduling counting instruction which will affect my drawing fps.

From the timeline when i load my page i always see an initial lag of 800ms (i haven't test it during a drawing phase since the code is not up yet) even if the code should never be reached (init values of currentValue and peak are "0" and timeOutTriggered is always false).

So my questions are:

1. Why do i have an initial lag of 800ms
2. Should i use n° web worker, one for each element of the array? if so how
3. Is there a better implementation? How are problem like this handled generally?

Animation is performed with RequestAnimationFrame btw.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1j0cz0m9/1/

Comment: Is `javascript` at Question with a loop? Can you create a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net to demonstrate issue?

Comment: It's really hard to get what you want to achieve with this code. But for **1**, this is because you the first call to `callback` is made in a `setTimeout(f, 800)`. Also note that your loop won't wait, so all your callbacks will fire with really little time between them. For **2**, dunno since we don't see what action is performed (if it's not too resources consumptive, no need for a WW). For **3**, yes definitely, you are already dealing with `rAF`, don't mix it with `setTimeout`or you'll get off sync. You have an high precision timestamp passed to rAF callback, use this to make your timing.

Comment: let's separate things:
At page just loaded there is no "first call to callback" since the if statement is always false. Why is the performance timeline reporting it in first place?
When the data is available i will have a mix between timer instruction and drawing instruction.
What do you mean with 2? the action is just that. Updating a max value, if no max value is received for 800 ms the max value is the current one

Comment: See here https://jsfiddle.net/1j0cz0m9/ . Open the performance timeline and hit F5 so it starts to record when the page is loaded. ~ 800ms junk frame is visible

Comment: @user217354 `peak is not defined` and that's true for your fiddle as for your question, we need more context to get what is happening. But anyway, except for curiosity, I'm not sure it worth the effort to debug this. You're in a X/Y dilemma.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1j0cz0m9/1/

fiddle updated, what do you mean with dilemma? If js is interpreted why it is reaching that instruction?
Moreover aside from this problem, what would it be a good solution to avoid setTimeout but have the problem solved when data are really available?

Comment: If you change your conditional as I outlined in my answer you should no longer get the 800ms delay. requestAnimationFrame is a better option than setTImeout.

Comment: I can't repro, I've got a 0.7ms  scripting in performance timeline. Do you see the console messages in this fiddle ? https://jsfiddle.net/1j0cz0m9/3/ I don't.

Comment: What is purpose of using both `setInterval` and `requestAnimationFrame`? Where are `interval` and `timer` defined?

Comment: var fps = 60; var interval = 1000 / fps; requestAnimationFrame can be used like that to achieve a defined fps value. timer is defined as null

Comment: see here in set a frame rate http://creativejs.com/resources/requestanimationframe/ aside from that which it can be removed, the problem is different

Comment: requestAnimationFrame will sync with the display framerate, setTimeout and setInterval are really not precise. If you want to draw only once every x frames, just check the timestamp passed as parameter of the callback function with which you called rAF. Any other solutions wil be out of sync. And even if it was possible, you could not be sure it fires on a screen refresh, so no point to do it.

Comment: Ok i'll remove it =) can we go back to the main problem? How do i solve the thing about the 800ms ? What should be the correct implementation?

Comment: In the end i decided to make a variable that count up to 18, since (60fps) 16.7ms * 18 ~= 300ms